# Reading/writing error messages from data factory pipelines

Tags: python, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

Going to try asking this here.

I'm trying to write an error message from an Azure Data Factory pipeline to a table in SQL server. It needs to capture the error message from a Databricks Python job. I can't find any official documentation and the method I have found from [this source](https://www.tech-findings.com/2019/06/ADF-Insert-Pipeline-details-in-Custom-Monitoring-Table.html):

@{activity('Proc source').error.message}

..doesn't write anything to the table. Just a blank string with no explanation.

Why data factory doesn't just have an area where you can view the details of errors instead of just saying "Failed" is beyond me. Or if it does, it's hidden away.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can someone please answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the details of error at here.

[image]

> @{activity('Proc source').error.message}

This expression works.

[image]

Is errorCode saved to your table?Make sure your activity name is correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! For some reason the error button you've pointed out isn't showing for me. The input and output options are, but the error button is simply missing. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Is status of your  copy data activity Failed?

Comment: I'm using a databricks python script as the first job, not a copy data activity and that's the job that's failing, if that makes any difference.

Comment: The strange thing is, if I remove the stored proc part of the pipeline, trigger it again and then head to pipeline runs in the monitoring section, It sort-of-but-not-really gives me an error:
"Operation on target ExtractMetadata (name of the databricks python operation) failed:" Then there's nothing underneath that. Is it possible it's just not throwing an error at all?

Comment: I haven't used databricks python ever.Maybe this don't give you error message.Do you get error code?

Comment: I get error code 3202, not sure what it means or why it can write the code but not a message.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

For anyone else reading this, the problem turned out to be something very stupid. I'd included a space in the python file name.
This returned an error code of 3202 and a blank error message.

I had another problem and resolution after this that I'd like to share, again for anyone frantically googling a solution to the problem. Once I'd removed spaces from the python filename, I logged an error code of '3204'
and the error message:  "Databricks execution failed with error message: . Run page url: (link to page showing clusters)". In the Databricks workspace launchable through the Azure portal, selecting a cluster through the 'clusters' sidebar then heading to 'Driver Logs' will show errors, in the 'Standard error' window that comes up.

I had already installed the libraries I needed on an existing cluster, but I'd forgotten to change a setting in the Databricks linked service. 'Select cluster' was set to 'new job cluster' when I needed 'Existing interactive cluster'. Thus, it wasn't pointing to the cluster I had expected.

These are all fairly small errors as it turns out, but again I hope that someone else dealing with the same issues will be able to find this post and save themselves some hassle!